# Custom middleware doesn't respect the update call of Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

**Description:**

I have a "logout" mechanism in my project. Basically, it creates a record into a DB table and I check if the `logged_out_at` has a value.

Now, to make sure this mechanism is proper, I've implemented it into a custom middleware that gets called whenever the `api` gets called.

```
[1] $record = Logout::where("user_id", Auth::id())->where("logged_out_at", null)->first()
```

When the logout record exists, I'd call `->update` and the set a value for `logged_out_at`. Then, redirect the user to a logout route or issue a `401 Not authorized` response.

```
[2] Logout::where("user_id", Auth::id())->where("logged_out_at", null)->update($params);
```

**Problem:**

Imagine the user clicking "refresh" or opening multiple microservices that request the `api` multiple times at the same time.

[1] will be called, [2] will be executed. In the second middleware call, the [1] will be called, the [2] of previous could be in execution process, therefore, I'd get a [1] valid response, which shouldn't be!

**Solution**

I've tried using `Redis` cache, use `Auth::id()` as key. If the cache exists, I return and don't search for anything. Nevertheless, I've faced the same problem. `Redis` would still take time to execute, save and retrieve the `pair`.

I've tried using a global variable (array with `Auth::id()` is key), but it would be a mess if I have over 1K users.

I believe my way of verifying the `logout` is wrong, but I couldn't find any helpful resources for this.

Comment: Where is the issue on returning a valid response microseconds after the user logged out? Is your system so sensitive that the logout needs to be literally instant ?

Comment: Because I'm sending a pusher notification and the pusher notification gets sent n times (n = the times the middleware gets called when the logout is valid) and it should be valid for once based on the logic above, but it's not due to the "microseconds"

Comment: You are sending the push notification before updating the field ? why not make it dependent on the update ? `->update()` returns the number of lines updated. if it's 1 send the notification. if 0 dont.

Comment: That's a good idea that I didn't think of, I'll try and see if it works, if so, you can post it then as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your needs are that an event (notification), that is triggered when you "logout", needs to trigger only once then you can make them tightly dependent via the result of the method `update()`

`update()` returns the number of rows affected by the query and since the query is conditioned on `logged_out_at` being `null` then:

```
$loggedOut = Logout::where("user_id", Auth::id())->where("logged_out_at", null)->update($params);
if ($loggedOut) {
    sendNotification();
}
```